# Normandy, France: Where to see the WW2 landing craft?

Tags: france, history, world-war-ii, normandy

I am visiting Normandy, France, more specifically the town of Bayeux. Where in vicinity (I have a car) is it possible to see landing craft used during operation Overlord on D-Day? Preferably on an actual beach and not in a museum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearest american landing craft can be seen in Overlord Museum near American Cemetery, Omaha beach.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [LCVP based at the harbour of Carentan-les-Marais](http://en.normandie-tourisme.fr/pcu/lcvp-higgins-boat,-american-landing-craft/carentan-les-marais/fiche-PCUNOR050V50C37N-2.html?iDD=6), about 50 km from Bayeux ([more details in French](http://www.ot-baieducotentin.fr/d-day-1944/carentan/barge-lcvp-pa30-4-port-de-carentan-marais/)). I don't think there is one on a beach anywhere, there might be one at the museum at Utah beach.

Answer (score 9):

The remains of [Mulberry harbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulberry_harbour) can be seen at [Arromanches-les-Bains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arromanches-les-Bains) on the French coast. There's also a small museum that displays dioramas depicting the harbour in operation.

[image]
<sup>Source: [Paris City Vision](https://www.pariscityvision.com/en/france/normandy/arromanches-les-bains)</sup>

Comment: I second this. You should absolutely go to the musem in Arromanches if you have the chance. It's quite small and quick to visit but absolutely worth it.There's a large window that lets you see the beach, with explanations about what happened, how they did it, etc., that adds so much to the overall experience. To me it felt like a window to history.